# How to work around errors thrown when downloading google drive files

Tags: python, google-api

I'm new to programming in python and have set up a program which uses the google drive API to download the 20 most recent pictures that have been stored on the drive. Everything has been working fine for the most part (credentials work, downloads work), but every once in a while I'll run into a file trying to download and google throws a 500 or 503 error. When this error is thrown, the program prints the error to the screen and then exits. I'm trying to get it to print the error, but then move to the next file.

With me receiving the error only once in a while (the software runs once per day), it's difficult for me to test any solutions because I can't replicate the issue whenever I'm testing.

The file download code is below:

```
def downloadImage(fh, request, filename):
    print(filename)
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        #print("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))
    try:
        with Image.open(folder + filename) as image:
            orientation = 274
            exif = image._getexif()
            if exif:
                exif = dict(exif.items())
                #print(exif)
                if exif[orientation] == 1:
                    print("EXIF says it's horizontal. Sending to build... >")
                    buildHorizontal(folder + filename)
                else:
                    resize_and_crop(folder + filename, folder + filename, (1920,1080), 'middle')
    except Exception as e:
        print("excptn:"+str(e))
        with Image.open(folder + filename) as image:
            w, h = image.size
            print( str(w) + " || " + str(h) )
            if int(h) < int(w) :
                print("It's a horizontal image. Sending to build... >")
                buildHorizontal(folder + filename)
```

I think I can fix the problem by adding a `try:` in the `while done is False` code block, but I'm not sure how to skip the file if an error is actually thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you can use a `try` block to make your program continue even if a error occurs, it is one of the use of the try statement. You just have to put the line provoking the error inside the `try` block

Comment: Would it then be something along the lines of while done is False: try: download except: Exception as e: print(e), then the program will continue on to the next file is there's an exception?